Is the perihelion precession formula of general relativity dimensionless? \[ \dot{\omega} =\frac{6 \pi G M}{c^2 a (1 - e^2)} \]
WHere:
G is the gravitational constant
M is the solar mass
c is the speed of light in vacuum
a the Mercury's semi-major axis
e the eccentricity of Mercury's orbit
I have tried several times but from the dimensional analysis it turns out that the right-hand side of that equation is dimensionless.
Am I wrong? I have taken this formula and the correspondent value from this web site of Rhode Island university https://phys.uri.edu/gerhard/PHY520/mln21.pdf and also at pag. 6 of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.3800
then in formula (13) of this paper: https://pubs.aip.org/aapt/ajp/article/90/11/857/2820267/Simple-precession-calculation-for-Mercury-A
and most importantly in eq. (1) of this article https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article-pdf/468/2/1405/11126982/stx548.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjI9LbY75CJAxUE_rsIHXLWH2wQFnoECDwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0TLWmAQ2Jk1NFVVWTPHOyg

Please define your symbols are at the least provide a link to the source that does.

I have just provided the link you asked

None of your references have $\dot\omega$, which is an angular acceleration, on the left side. They all have a dimensionless angle on the left. Why are you misrepresenting your own references?

Ok see this document    https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article-pdf/468/2/1405/11126982/stx548.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjI9LbY75CJAxUE_rsIHXLWH2wQFnoECDwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0TLWmAQ2Jk1NFVVWTPHOyg    It is clearly  wrtitten that the equation is in radians/revolution but is dimensionless instead

And please [edit] the equation into the body of your question. A title is not the question.

What should I edit?

Your question talks about an equation, but there is no equation in your question body, only in the title. The equation doesn't need to be in the title, but it should be in the question body. Please do not treat the title as the first line of the question body.

It is clearly wrtitten that the equation is in radians/revolution but is dimensionless instead. Radians are a dimensionless unit. The number of revolutions is dimensionless. Their ratio is therefore dimensionless.

Yes but the precession velocity is an angular velocity whose dimension should be 1/T not 1

This is not an angular velocity. Suppose the perihelion precesses by 1 arc second every revolution. That is a meaningful angle regardless of whether the revolution took 1 year or 1 day. If you want the angular velocity of precession you have to divide by the period of the revolution.

I can rewrite you formula as:
$$ \dot\omega = 3\pi \frac{R_s} {a(1-\epsilon^2)} $$
The RHS is the ratio of two distances, so that is dimensionless.
The LHS, you have:
$$ \omega \rightarrow [T]^{-1}$$
$$ \frac d {dt} \rightarrow [T]^{-1}$$
so that has $[T]^{-2}$.
Something is wrong. $\omega$ must not be an angular frequency: what is it?
Per Zero's comment: the LHS is (from the link):
"The angle δθ of precession per cycle"
Here, and change in an angle is dimensionless (radians notwithstanding), while cycle is a bit confusing. It's not a period; rather it is in integer count, so, the LHS is:
$$ \frac{[{\rm rad}]}{[1]} \rightarrow [1] $$
which is dimensionless.

They are close my question. Anyway if you remake the dimensional analisys you will see that the right hand side is dimensionless

@RobertoNapolitano nobody challenges that the RHS is dimensionless: the point is the LHS is not dimensionless as written.  It has units of $[T]^{-2}$ as a rate of change of an angular velocity.  Also note that your first link does not give the lhs as $\dot\omega$ but as $\delta\vartheta$ which is dimensionless.

I have learmed at university that LHS and RHS of an equation must have the same dimensions, or must be both dimensionless, otherwise the equation is wrong

OP's equation is wrong... $d\theta$ is an integral of $\omega$, not a derivative of it.

See this document    https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article-pdf/468/2/1405/11126982/stx548.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjI9LbY75CJAxUE_rsIHXLWH2wQFnoECDwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0TLWmAQ2Jk1NFVVWTPHOyg    It is clearly  wrtitten that the equation is in radians/revolution but is dimensionless instead

Radians are dimensionless; it can’t be dimensionless “instead”

The OP is in error.
The expression given in this document
is
$$
\delta\vartheta=\frac{6\pi G M}{c^2 a(1-e^2)} \tag{1}
$$
and the left hand side is NOT equal to $\dot\omega$.  $\delta\vartheta$ is an angle and thus as such dimensionless since angles are ratios of lengths.  Thus, the LHS of (1) is indeed dimensionless, as is the RHS.
At best, $\delta\vartheta=\int \omega ,dt$ rather than $\frac{d}{dt} \omega$.
